PromptLayer: OpenAI connection that doesn't use an environment variable
I'm getting blocked from deploying PromptLayer.run() because of the requirement to use .env file. In production I cannot use a .env but can inject api keys.
I'm looking at runnning PromptLayer on a Lambda that calls out to OpenAI. Following the docs I want to run this code
promptlayer = PromptLayer(api_key="pl_xxx")

OpenAI = promptlayer.openai.OpenAI
client = OpenAI(api_key="sk-xxx")

promptlayer.run(
    prompt_name="some_te3mplate", input_variables={"raw_text": "hello there"}
)

but am getting the error OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the openai_api_name environment variable.
This seems to only be fixable by creating a .env file in my project but this is not possible for me in production as I store secrets in SecretManager that are injected at runtime (and I don't want to store raw api keys in a lambda config).
Is there a way to fix this error?
